# Bootstrap 3.0.2 - How to keep 2 collapsable navbars but showing one of them only when collapsed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I already managed to have 2 collapsable navbars working perfectly on Bootstrap 3.0.2 - both navbars collapse to 2 nice buttons that allow to access each navbar isolatedly.

The point is that now I need to keep one of the navbars hidden while on -sm,-md and -lg and only show up on -xs.

The easiest would be to set "hidden-sm, hidden-md, hidden-lg" on the navbar (what really works) but we get an side effect of "showing the collapsed menu" whenever I switch to -xs (due to the hiddens set-up) - is there a way to avoid expanding de menu on -xs, or another way to hide the navbar while on -sm,-md and -lg?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a [Bootply](http://bootply.com) with your code?

Answer (score 1):

I would say, simply use `.visible-xs` :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse visible-xs" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
            data-toggle="collapse" 
            data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">...</div>
</nav>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
            data-toggle="collapse" 
            data-target="#navbar-collapse-2">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-2">...</div>
</nav>
```

**[Bootply](http://bootply.com/97386)**